# Long length of wire off of GPIO pins

Tags: gpio, pi-2, electronics

I am building a circuit with the Raspberry Pi that requires a button about fifty feet away from the central circuit. I am planning on using speaker wire for the connection from the Pi to the button. Is this an OK solution? If so, what gauge of wire should I use, or does it matter? If it isn't an OK solution, what should I use instead?

Comment: Not really a Pi question.  More suited to an electrical site I would have thought.  Who can say?  If it works it works, it depends on the environment through which the wires are running.  Twisted pair as is found in cat 5 cable may be a better choice as it has better immunity to interference.

Comment: For right now, I'm going to use a 16 gauge speaker wire, and if it doesn't work, I'll try a cat 5 cable like @joan suggested.

Answer (score 2):

In fact, while this question if not specifically Pi oriented, it is (marginally) relevant to using the GPIO on a long cable.

The wire gauge is irrelevant.

You are in fact connecting an antenna to the GPIO, so you should minimise interference.

Twisted pair is a good idea, but a pair like speaker wire is acceptable.

You should avoid running the wire parallel to any other circuitry.

The most important is to use a low impedance circuit - i.e. a low value Pull up (say 470Ω) near the Pi itself.

Comment: Do you think that an RC low pass would additionally help EMI issues besides low impedance of the setup?

Comment: @Ghanima It wouldn't hurt, but unless the environment is next to a transmitter the signal level you can get on 15m cable would be low enough to cause no problem, provided it is terminated.

Answer (score 1):

Speaker wire is not ideal, but is *"not-too-bad"* if it's twisted. It *might* work untwisted, but 50 feet is a rather long distance. The primary cause of concern with untwisted speaker wire is that you are connecting to a very high-impedance input; i.e. the GPIO pin. This creates *headaches* if the *pickup mechanism* is [electromagnetic induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_induction). The current generated is quite small, but with a current source the voltage depends upon... ***the impedance***. It's not unusual to see *several volts* produced under these circumstances. Contrast this (high-impedance) situation with the situation encountered when using speaker wire with **speakers** (i.e. low-impedance) where the impedance of the speakers is generally in the *4-to-8 ohm* range. Even a few milliamps of induced current won't be noticed!

To avoid potential problems simply requires following a few simple ***guidelines***. Let's go over a few basics:

1. Long-ish cables can act as an antenna to pick up "EMI", so you'll need a simple "filter" to squelch spurious signals. We'll cover the filter design in a moment.
2. Using a twisted, shielded wire pair can help reduce noise pickup. If you don't have a STP (shielded twisted pair) wire, simply "twist" the pair of wires you do have. A twist every inch or two will be fine. Shielding is great, but its primary benefit is in reducing emissions from your wiring, whereas you are concerned with *susceptibility* of your wiring to outside interference.
3. Situations vary! You will have some spots in your home/office that have more interference than others. Consider this when you're planning your signal wire routing, and try to avoid adjacency to large current users (ovens, heat pumps, etc).

The "filter":
I'll assume you don't have a lot of instrumentation, and so we'll approach this as a trial-and-error effort. Keep things simple... it's silly to worry about problems you don't have - you'll never run out of problems to solve, so don't waste time solving those that don't exist. That said, the filter you should start with is very simple: a 0.1 uF capacitor. Place it near your GPIO pin: one end to the GPIO pin, the other to Ground.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fnkMwW.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If you find that you are detecting "false triggers" from time to time, perhaps the easiest thing to try first is a "software timer". In other words, when your GPIO pin is pulled to its "active" state, start a counter in software; count to perhaps 500 msec, then check the GPIO pin again. If it's in the "triggered" state (active), then you have a "real event". If it's not, it was a spurious signal.