# Raspberry Pi 3B+ input pin strange behavior

Tags: gpio, pi-3b+, input-device

I have few switches connected to Raspberry Pi inputs.
Internal pull up resistors are enabled.
When I connect pin to the ground Raspberry Pi behave fine - pin state is low.
However when I disconnect the pin from the ground it randomly change the state every few seconds.
I have tried to add external 10k pull up resistor but it haven't worked.
Pull up resistor is connected near Raspberry Pi.
Switch is connected by 7 meters UTP 5e cable.
I use pi4j library.
[image]

Comment: Please add a photo of the connections.  An external 10k resistor should be enough to stop the input floating. A listing of the software will also be useful.

Comment: I have updated description and added picture

Comment: Perhaps the 7 metres of cable is too much for a 10 k resistor.  As an experiment do you get a problem if you connect to GPIO 2 or 3 (they have 1k8 pulls to 3V3 fitted).

Comment: related if not dupe: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/57951/19949 and https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/93834/19949 (the length of the cable - now edited into the question - might be an issue... try decreasing the pull-up)

Comment: Actually I have problem with pins 4,5,13,14, and 29.
I couldn't find Raspberry Pi 3B+ electric schema

Comment: @mariusz2108, have you tried shorter wire and smaller pullup?

Comment: Not yet. But I have longer wire about 10 meters and use only internal pull up and it works fine

Answer (score 0):

If you are actually using **GPIO0** (pin 27) this is actually SDA.0 which is used to control HATs and is marked reserved on official documentation.

I believe on newer Pi models this I²C bus is also connected to on-board extenders so is used for other purposes, although this is not documented, expect the voltage on this pin to change unexpectedly.

Use any ot the other pins (and a low impedance circuit).

Comment: Actually I have problem with GPIO pins 4,5,13,14, and 29 of 3B+. I couldn't find Raspberry Pi 3B+ electric schema